# How do access the property of the child control?

Tags: c#, wpf

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.

I have created two custom control.
First control has a DP named CaretIndexFromLine and the control name is TextArea.
The following is the summarized cs code of the first control.

```
public class TextArea : TextBox
{
    public int CaretIndexFromLine
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CaretIndexFromLineProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(CaretIndexFromLineProperty , value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaretIndexFromLineProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CaretIndexFromLine", typeof(int), typeof(TextArea), new P 
        ropertyMetadata(0));
   ...
}
```

The second control named Editor has child control TextArea.

The following is the summarized XAML code of the second control.

```
<Editor> <TextArea x:Name="PART_TextArea"/> </Editor>
```

And the following is summarized cs code of the second control.

```
public class Editor : Control
{
    public TextArea TextArea { get; private set; }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        this.TextArea = (TextArea)Template.FindName("PART_TextArea", this);
    }

    ...
}
```

And I was going to use the above control in the MainWindow.

```
<MainWindow> <Editor/> </MainWindow>
```

There is a problem here.
I want to access the property (CaretIndex) of the TextArea in the XAML code.
I tried like this but It was not operated.

```
<MainWindow>
  <StackPanel>
    <Editor x:Name="editor"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=editor.TextArea, Path=CaretIndexFromLine}/>
  </StackPanel>
</MainWindow>
```

What should I do to achieve the above goal?

Thank you for reading this and please teach me the solution.

Comment: create `CaretIndexFromLine` in `Editor` as well?

Comment: Do I need to create the property of a TextArea at the Editor over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Editor` control has an `TextArea` property so just set the `ElementName` to "editor" and the `Path` to `TextArea.CaretIndexFromLine`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=editor, Path=TextArea.CaretIndexFromLine}/>
```

`TextArea` should be a read-only dependency property though in order for a notification to be raised when it's set in the `OnApplyTemplate()` method.

Comment: It is good to do what you say.
In fact, previous I tried the above the XAML code.
But at that time it did not operate because of TextArea is not DP.
Previous I didn't know it that to receive DP value of TextArea in MainWindow, TextArea also must be DP.
Thank you for your answer.